# ImageResizing with s3reader not working

Tags: amazon-s3, imageresizer

I have problems with the s3reader plugin with imageresizer.

I m using Image resizer to resize the amazon images.

I have tried to open the image url directly, it works fine there but it doesn't work when i apply resizing on the image (e.g. https://s3.amazonaws.com/refpstaging/property/16594/16594_1.jpeg works but this http://www.example.com/s3/refpstaging/property/16594/16594_1.jpeg?width=100 doesn't). The same code and configuration works locally fine for me. In other words, it works when i use **localhost/s3/refpstaging/property/16594/16594_1.jpeg?width=100**

I m already using Licence binaries. Also confirmed that folder has full permissions to IIS.

I m using MVC and have installed MvcRoutingShim plugin properly

My Disgnostics output is as under.

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      12/17/2013 12:44:27 PM

1 Issues detected:

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.

You are using paid bundles: Cloud Bundle, Performance Bundle

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.MvcRoutingShim.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader.S3Reader
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache

Configuration:

<resizer>
<pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
<diskCache dir="~/imagecache" autoClean="false" hashModifiedDate="true" enabled="true" subfolders="32" cacheAccessTimeout="15000" asyncWrites="false" asyncBufferSize="10485760" />
<plugins>
<add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
<add name="S3Reader" buckets="refpstaging,refp,refpstaging" prefix="~/s3/" />
<add name="DiskCache" />
</plugins>
</resizer>

Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, scale,         stretch, crop, cropxunits, cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip,         sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc, frame,         useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode, zoom, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/7.5 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 and CLR         4.0.30319.1008
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: AMD64
Executing assembly: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1008  Info: 4.0.30319.1008
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1016  Info: 4.0.30319.1016
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1015  Info: 4.0.30319.1015
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1015  Info: 4.0.30319.1015
System.Data.SqlXml                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1015  Info: 4.0.30319.1015
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237   Info: 4.0.30319.237
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237   Info: 4.0.30319.237
System.Transactions                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Numerics                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Microsoft.Build.Framework                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 10.0.30319.296  Info: 10.0.30319.296
System.Web.Mvc                           Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.20105.0    
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.WebPages                      Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.WebPages.Razor                Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.Razor                         Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data.Linq                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1015  Info: 4.0.30319.1015
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1016  Info: 4.0.30319.1016
Real Estate Fan Pages                    Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Cassette.Views                           Assembly: 2.0.0.17975     File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
REFP.Core                                Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Stripe.net                               Assembly: 1.2.0.0        
FluentValidation.Mvc                     Assembly: 3.2.0.0         File: 3.2.0.0        
EntityFramework                          Assembly: 4.1.0.0         File: 4.1.10331.0     Info: 4.1.10331.0
System.Data.Entity                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1016  Info: 4.0.30319.1016
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Data.OracleClient                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
FluentValidation                         Assembly: 3.2.0.0         File: 3.2.0.0        
Cassette                                 Assembly: 2.0.0.17974     File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EntityFramework Assembly: 1.0.0.0        
EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-REFP.Core  Assembly: 1.0.0.0        
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
SMDiagnostics                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Xaml.Hosting                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Elmah                                    Assembly: 1.2.13605.0     File: 1.2.13605.2128 
Cassette.Aspnet                          Assembly: 2.0.0.17975     File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
AjaxMin                                  Assembly: 4.60.4609.17023
AWSSDK                                   Assembly: 1.5.16.1        File: 1.5.16.1       
BCrypt.Net                               Assembly: 0.1.4056.18965  File: 0.1.0.0        
CKFinder                                 Assembly: 2.2.0.1326     
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 3.3.3.123       File: 3.3.3.123       Info: 3-3-3  Commit: c368317
ImageResizer.Mvc                         Assembly: 3.3.3.123       File: 3.3.3.123       Info: 3-3-3  Commit: c368317
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache           Assembly: 3.3.3.123       File: 3.3.3.123       Info: 3-3-3  Commit: c368317
ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader            Assembly: 3.3.3.123       File: 3.3.3.123       Info: 3-3-3  Commit: c368317
librets-dotnet                           Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
LinqKit                                  Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Newtonsoft.Json                          Assembly: 4.5.0.0         File: 4.5.3.14814    
REFP                                     Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
RestSharp                                Assembly: 102.7.0.0       File: 102.7.0.0      
RouteDebug                               Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Utilities                                Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
System.Web.Abstractions                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Helpers                       Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.Routing                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Design                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237   Info: 4.0.30319.237
System.Web.Mobile                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
```

Please help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say it 'doesn't work'. What is the error message you get when you try to visit the image URL directly? 404? 500? If it's 500, follow the troubleshooting guide to enable detailed error messages. We can't help without the error message.

Comment: Also, you're using 3.3.3 instead of the current version, 3.4.2. The latest version has better diagnostics information, and also supports AWSSDK 2.0 with S3Reader2. For troubleshooting purposes, try resizing an image physically located on the app.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist: Thanks for the reply. I get 404 when i visit the image url directly (http://www.example.com/s3/bucket/folder/image.jpeg gives 404). I will try using the latest version.

Comment: Did you resolve this? If so, please post the answer that resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. Actually it was the problem with the server. When i tried the same code deploying to other server, it worked. So nothing with the code, it was having some problems with the server i was deploying.

Thanks you all for your support.